# Lines overlaping in same layer - PostGIS

Tags: postgis, overlapping-features, linestring

I have lines overlapping in one layer as in image below. How do I delete one of these lines and leave the other one in the dataset?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use an SQL query to delete them.

Before doing so, be warned that it can lead to surprises should more than 2 lines intersects each others. It is also suspicious to delete a random line between the two intersecting ones. --> make a backup before deleting anything.

That being said, the query would refer twice to the same table: once for deleting the rows and once for identifying intersecting rows.

The line `tmp.id < t1.id` is used to delete the line having the smallest ID between the two intersecting ones. It also filter self deletion (a line intersects itself)

```
DELETE 
FROM t1 
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 
  FROM t1 tmp 
  WHERE tmp.id < t1.id
   AND ST_INTERSECTS(tmp.geom, t1.geom));
```

Comment: Hi, this worked super. Just wondering how does it work. I am unsure what `SELECT 1 FROM t1 tmp` is doing? I dont understand what `1` or tmp means in this case. Thanks

Comment: @user1655130 See this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159413/exists-select-1-vs-exists-select-one-or-the-other). Basically you can `select` whatever you want (`1`,`*`,`null` ... or event nothing at all), the `exists` keyword is the important one (get from t1 any row that match the content of the  `exists` clause). As for `tmp` is it just a table alias. You can't use `t1` directly as if it used in the `delete from t1`, so you assign a temporary name